# pack and go not using edited dimensions for saving

Tags: c#, cad, solidworks

I am trying to use pack and go function with C# API.
I did get it working but the problem that i am facing is it is not saving edited dimensions.
The dimensions are edited using API and it is reflecting well in solidworks but when I try saving the assemblies and parts using Pack and Go, it is using old dimensions.
Did I missed something?

Answer (score 1):

Actually that was a bug on SolidWorks API. I was using SolidWorks API 2012 and it is impossible to do "pack and go" and obtain newly modified data without saving it once. You can get modified dimension data only once you save your data doing some silent save.

```
swModel.Save2(true);
```

So my approach was to store a base model into one temp directory, load model from original directory, change it's parameters, save it silently, do pack and go and replace the original data with temp data.

Just sharing my approach for this problem solving.